# Why students do not notice sign of plus/minus?

Tags: primary-education

My child in grade 3 often needs a reminder because in a task where he needs to do addition he would subtract instead of adding  or v.v ignoring the signs given in a task. He would also forget adding carry.

Why this happens and what can be done to ensure that he does not commit this mistake in future?

He understands the procedure as well as concept but he often commits this silly mistake. What kind of task should be given to him so that he keeps the sign in mind before and during solving the task?

Comment: Has his vision been checked? When I first got glasses, towards the end of 6th grade (age 12), I couldn't read the 20-200 E's at the top of standard eye charts (nearly all due to near sightedness, so I could read books fine), but I had no idea that others could see so well at distances (not sure why, but it never seemed to come up; I happened to sit on the front row in my classes in the years preceding 6th grade) despite spending quite a bit of my after school time those years playing in the several hundred acres of unpopulated woods and fields (owned by someone else) behind our house.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. He is not having any vision related issues as far as our assessment is concerned. But shall get his eyes professionally tested. Nevertheless I have seen this issue with many children. In fact even I used to commit this same mistake, despite the fact that at 42 I have no problems with eyesight.

Comment: The thing with vision is that there could be astigmatism that might cause difficulty in distinguishing - and + signs, or eye tracking issues.